# Selenium: Verify visiblity of radio option and its label.

Tags: xpath, selenium

Hi i have the following simple radio button

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioOption1" value="option1">
    System option1. 
</label>
```

How would i use selenium to verify the radio button and its label is not visible.

```
selenium.isVisible("//input[@name='radioOption1' and @value='option1']");
```

would verify if the option is not visible but i want to verify the whole label is not visible.

Comment: When you say label will not be visible you meant, the element is present in the page but not visible? isElementPresent(//label(contains(text(),'System option1')) will return true when its not visible?

Comment: nah i mean the whole label and the radio option is not visible. Also i want to be able to use value of the radio option since it allows me to change the label like from System option1 to Sys option 1. So the entire <label> </label>

Comment: What language? Selenium RC or Web Driver?

Answer (score 1):

xpath has a parent pseudo-pointer, not so sure about Selenium implemetation

```
//parent::input[@name='radioOption1' and @value='option1']
```

or

```
//label[./input[@name='radioOption1' and @value='option1']]
```